# Sencha Phonegap Android Push Notification

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, push-notification

I am developing a sencha touch application which need push notification functionality. I know according to sencha docs they are not supporting Android push notification. So am trying to integrate my project with Phonegap 3.0. For push notification am using this plugin 
https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample30/

The demo is working fine am getting registration id, i can sent push notification to that reg id. But the problem is when i try to integrate my sencha app to this demo push plugin am not getting the reg id

my index.html look like this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>crmapp</title>
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appLoadingIndicator">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And am calling the push notification function in js/index.js file from my app.js file its looks like this way

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'WinReo',
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',

    ],


    views: [
        'Login',
       // 'MainMenu',
        'CrmFooter',
        'CrmHead',



    ],
    controllers:[
        'Login',
        'Main',
        'Task',

    ],
    models: [
        'Event',
        "Task"
    ],
    stores: [
        'Events',
        'EventsDueListStore'
        //'Contactsstore'
    ],


    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function() {

        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
        app.initialize(); // **Please see this line**

    },
    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Here is the index.js file

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"675077458226","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    successHandler: function(result) {
        alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
    },
    errorHandler:function(error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                    alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
                    document.write(e.regid);
                }
                break;

            case 'message':
                // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
                break;

            case 'error':
                alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
                break;

            default:
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                break;
        }
    }

};
```

Am not sure is it the way to call this function, am not getting access to that function at all, not getting registration id.. Please guid me in right direction.. is it the way to call phonegap function from sencha touch ? Am struck with issue, Please help me solve this issue, Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to pass the {application name}.app.onNotificationGCM for ecb. Look in your app.js file, and say your name is 'MyApp'. Then, it would be MyApp.app.onNotificationGCM. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you managae to solve this, i found the solution

Instead of adding the push registration code in your cordova's **index.js**, add it directly into your Sencha's **app.js** launch function

```
launch: function() {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler,{"senderID":"675077458226","ecb":"MyAppName.app.onNotificationGCM"});
 },
 //then followed by your othe functions
 receivedEvent: function(id)
  {
    //code here
  },
 errorHandler:function(error) {
   //code here
   },
 onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
  //code here
  }
```

And also note that i changed how the functions are called, **app.successHandler** to **this.successHandler**, **"this"** refers to your app, and also **app.onNotificationGCM** to **MyAppName.app.onNotificationGCM**

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet inside your app's lanch method

```js
var pushNotification;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == "amazon-fireos" ){
                pushNotification.register(
                 function(result){
                    alert('result = ' + result);
                },
                function(error){
                    alert('error = ' + error);
                },
                {
                    "senderID":"YOUR_google_project_id",
                    "ecb":"onNotification"
                });
            }
            onNotification = function(e) {
                alert("aaa"+JSON.stringify(e));
            }

        });
```